# Store Contact Form submissions

Tags: plugin-contactform

I am coming to Craft from Perch Runway so am trying to work out how to replicate some functionality from one to the other.

With Runway any form submissions, as well as being emailed to specified addresses, are stored on the database and viewable through the admin area.

I have installed the Contact Forms plugin for Craft (https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form) and was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing with this? Or do I need to look at another plugin / some custom functionality for this?

It is a helpful feature as emails are sometimes missed / fail to deliver etc.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also recently come from Runway to Craft and had the exact same requirement. The [Contact Form Extension plugin](https://github.com/Rias500/craft-contact-form-extensions) that does exactly what you need

I did have to create a Craft Module though on one site to get validation working on the name field.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. The contact-form plugin of craft is rather `rough` around the edges. I especially miss a error-handling. The form plugin just fails silently.

As a replacement I'd go for

- [AM Forms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms)
- [Sospace's Freeform](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/)